# How to clear a rectangle area in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

WebGL has a `clear` method that clears an entire surface.  What's the best way to clear just a particular rectangle of the surface?  For example I want to set a 100x100 box of pixels starting at (50, 50) to all zeroes (ARGB 0, 0, 0, 0).  All I can think of right now is drawing a quad with a fragment shader that writes zeroes.  Is there not an easier way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the SCISSOR test to constrain clearing (and rendering in general) to a rectangle.

```
// turn on the scissor test.
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

// set the scissor rectangle.
gl.scissor(x, y, width, height);

// clear.
gl.clearColor(r, g, b, a);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ...);

// turn off the scissor test so you can render like normal again.
gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
```

Comment: I'm playing with three.js, and I don't understand difference between viewport area and scissor area. I mean, if I want to put more viewport I have to set scissor area and enabling scissor test. Can u explain this thing? :)

Comment: The viewport command sets 2 things. The values that coordinates are clipped to and the value that coordinates are multiplied by to convert them into pixels from clipsace. Note I didn't say they clip pixels. If you set the viewport say 100,100,1,1 (a 1 pixel viewport) and you draw point setting `gl_PointSize` to 10 you'll still see it draw  a 10 pixel point (outside the viewport). That's because the viewport settings only clip the vertices. scissor on the other hand clips pixels.

Comment: could the canvas background be transparent for webGL (clear without color)?

Comment: Yes, set the clear color to 0,0,0,0 (eg `gl.clearColor(0,0,0,0)`) which is the default. That will see through the canvas whatever is behind it or its background CSS style if one is set.

Answer (score 0):

anything outside the viewport if within the webgl context will be drawn, anything outside scissor will be clipped and not drawn at all !