# Clear Canvas in FireFox not working - "clearRect not a function" error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have canvas element which run webgl application.
I'm trying to clear the canvas with `clearRect` but I get error msg:

```
"TypeError: context.clearRect is not a function"
```

Im using FireFox 49.0.2 if that matters.
Anyone know why?

**html:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style=width="1800" height="1000"></canvas>
```

**JS:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("webgl");
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with webgl, but clearRect is a function of a 2d context, so if you change to `canvas.getContext("2d");`

Comment: webgl doesn't have the same functions as 2d

Comment: tnx @TomásAntunes, is there a way to clear canvas containing Webgl?

Comment: @Jon - this command return `null`

Comment: In WebGL the clear() method clears buffers to preset values specified by clearColor(), clearDepth() and clearStencil()

Comment: @TomásAntunes -  But when I keep drawing after these clear functions the new content just added to the first  content

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: [This previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11544608/6854845) is about clearing a rectangle in webgl.